# SupportMapFragment get recreated on orientation change

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm creating a simple app that use google maps in a tab and something else in other.
The problem is that the map gets recreated when i change orientation so i goes to latlng 0,0

Here is my Code

#### MainAcitivy.java

```
private static final String MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG = "map";
private static final String DUMMY_FRAGMENT_TAG = "DUMMY";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //
    // // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar
        .newTab()
            .setText(R.string.title_section1)
                .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<SupportMapFragment>(this,
                        MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG, SupportMapFragment.class)));
    actionBar
        .addTab(actionBar
            .newTab()
                .setText(R.string.title_section2)
                    .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<DummySectionFragment>(this,
                            DUMMY_FRAGMENT_TAG,
                                DummySectionFragment.class)));

}
```

#### TabListener.java

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag,
    Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        }
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

[image: Portrait oriented near Congo]

[image: Landscape oriented at latlng(0,0)]

Comment: Well, in my case, the problem was that I was resetting the map camera in `onCreate()` of the activity. Otherwise, `SupportMapFragment` seems to retain its `CameraPosition` across configuration changes, even without `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: I don't know why it's happening but with the *android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"* is now working

Comment: for me also worked fine alvaro answer android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in the onCreate method of your MapFragment

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and this question & even its answer helped me.

But exactly I was having problem with:

- Google Map (Issue: Clears / Refreshes)
- ProgressDialog running with AsyncTask (Issue: Crashes)
- Dialog (Issue: Cancels)

So to go through all these issues, I have added the below code with every activity.

```
<activity
            android:name="ACTIVITY"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

It worked for me, so though it'll help other too as it's a common issue.